# Given a website's HTML in a string, how to extract tag elements?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.home.com");
myRequest.Method = "GET";
WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), 
                                   System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
myResponse.Close();
```

The string contains whole html of that webpage, now I want to extract html tags from  that string.

How do I that?

Answer (score 6):

Having [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) makes it peace of cake parsing HTML content.
You can see examples [here](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples).

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
 {
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
    att.Value = FixLink(att);
 }
 doc.Save("file.htm");
```

Comment: hey, i have string containing whole html page, nt html file.
So ihave to parse that string not html file...

Comment: @asmi, well, in that case, replace doc.Load with doc.LoadHtml(result) and it should work.